# Failed to start broker after enabling Zookeeper Authentication

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl

**Started Zookeeper with the following properties ie zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeepeeer              
clientPort=2186        
maxClientCnxns=0        
auto.offset.reset=smallest        
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider       
jaasLoginRenew=3600000        
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

**zookeeper_jaas.conf**

```
Server {        
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required        
    username="admin"        
    password="admin-secret"        
    user_admin="admin-secret";        
};
```

**Server.properties**

```
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0        
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer        
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092        
security.inter.broker.protocol= SASL_PLAINTEXT        
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN        
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN        
super.users=User:admin        
zookeeper.set.acl=true
```

**Kafka_server_jaaz.conf**

```
KafkaServer {        
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required        
    username="admin"        
    password="admin-secret"        
    user_admin="admin-secret";        
};
```

**The error is as follows**
`java.lang.SecurityException: zookeeper.set.acl is true, but the verification of the JAAS login file failed.`

I have tried the below solution but it again fails with the following error inspite of doing the  changes

**kafka_server_jaaz.conf**

```
KafkaServer {        
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="admin-secret"
user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="admin-secret";
};
```

**The server.properties is the same as above**
But it fails with the following error:
[2018-02-23 10:16:04,459] ERROR Invalid ACL (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2018-02-23 10:16:04,459] ERROR Invalid ACL (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2018-02-23 10:16:04,460] FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer
       startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException:
       org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka you also need to configure the SASL client which will be used when connecting to Zookeeper. This is done using the `Client` context in the Kafka JAAS config, e.g.

```
Client {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret";
};
```

If needed, the context name can be changed using the `zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig` system property.

Comment: Thank you for your promt reply will try it out and get back to you